# PHP using jquery to create multiple image upload and multiple textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to use jquery to create multiple image upload with multiple textbox function. But the problem is how to pass to value of the textarea to database. Upload Image can work, but the description cannot pass into database

Can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

```
//main.php
<div class="modal fade" id="photo-modal" role="dialog">
<form method="post" action="upload-photo-action.php" autocomplte="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text"  name="counter" id="counter" />
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog1">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Adding description</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="file" style="display:none" id="upload1" name="image_file_photo[]" multiple>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-upload" id="upload-image1" onclick="upload_photo();">Upload Photos From File</button>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="container-fluid" id="image" style="width:100%; max-height: 250px; overflow:auto;padding-left:0; padding-right:0;display:none;"></div>
                <!-- end of container-fluid -->
            </div><!-- end of modal-body-->
            <div class="modal-footer" style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: center; display: none;" id="save_btn">
                <input type="submit" name="upload_pho" id="upload_pho" class="btn btn-save" value="Save">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function upload_photo(){
        $('#image').css("display", "block");
        $('#save_btn').css("display", "block");
    }
    var count1=0;
    function handleFileSelect1(evt) {
        var $fileUpload1 = $("input#upload1[type='file']");
        count1=count1+parseInt($fileUpload1.get(0).files.length);

        if (parseInt($fileUpload1.get(0).files.length) > 11 || count1>10) {
          alert("You can only upload a maximum of 10 files");
          count1=count1-parseInt($fileUpload1.get(0).files.length);
          evt.preventDefault();
          evt.stopPropagation();
          return false;
        }

        var files1 = evt.target.files;
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files1[i]; i++) {
          if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
          }
          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
          counter1 = parseInt($fileUpload1.get(0).files.length);
            return function (e) {
            var span1 = document.createElement('span');
            span1.innerHTML = ['<div style="width:24%; height: 60%; display: inline-block;"><img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; border-radius: 0;" /><textarea rows="2" name="img_desc" id="img_desc" style="max-width: 100%;" placeholder="Add description"></textarea><span class="remove_img_preview1"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></span></div><div style="display:inline-block;">&nbsp;</div>'].join(''); 
              document.getElementById('image').insertBefore(span1, null);
            };
          })(f);
          reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    }
</script>
///
////upload-photo-action.php
if(isset($_POST['upload_pho'])){
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['image_file_photo']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['image_file_photo']['name'][$key];
        $file_size = $_FILES['image_file_photo']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['image_file_photo']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type = $_FILES['image_file_photo']['type'][$key];
        $image_desc = $_POST['img_desc'];


        //if($file_size > 2097152){
            //$errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        //}

        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mt_image SET image_name = '".$file_name."',
                                                       image_size = '".$file_size."',
                                                       image_tmp = '".$file_tmp."',
                                                       image_desc = '".$image_desc."',
                                                       image_type = '".$file_type."'")or die(mysql_error());
        $desired_dir = "img_upload";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
        }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;                
        }
            mysql_query($query);            
        }else{
            print_r($errors);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code.
1. textarea should be an array.

```
//main.php
    <div class="modal fade" id="photo-modal" role="dialog">
    <form method="post" action="upload-photo-action.php" autocomplte="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text"  name="counter" id="counter" />
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog1">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Adding description</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="file" style="display:none" id="upload1" name="image_file_photo[]" multiple>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-upload" id="upload-image1" onclick="upload_photo();">Upload Photos From File</button>
                    <div>&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="container-fluid" id="image" style="width:100%; max-height: 250px; overflow:auto;padding-left:0; padding-right:0;display:none;"></div>
                    <!-- end of container-fluid -->
                </div><!-- end of modal-body-->
                <div class="modal-footer" style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: center; display: none;" id="save_btn">
                    <input type="submit" name="upload_pho" id="upload_pho" class="btn btn-save" value="Save">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function upload_photo(){
            $('#image').css("display", "block");
            $('#save_btn').css("display", "block");
        }
        var count1=0;
        function handleFileSelect1(evt) {
            var $fileUpload1 = $("input#upload1[type='file']");
            count1=count1+parseInt($fileUpload1.get(0).files.length);

            if (parseInt($fileUpload1.get(0).files.length) > 11 || count1>10) {
              alert("You can only upload a maximum of 10 files");
              count1=count1-parseInt($fileUpload1.get(0).files.length);
              evt.preventDefault();
              evt.stopPropagation();
              return false;
            }

            var files1 = evt.target.files;
            for (var i = 0, f; f = files1[i]; i++) {
              if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                continue;
              }
              var reader = new FileReader();

              reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
              counter1 = parseInt($fileUpload1.get(0).files.length);
                return function (e) {
                var span1 = document.createElement('span');
                span1.innerHTML = ['<div style="width:24%; height: 60%; display: inline-block;"><img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; border-radius: 0;" /><textarea rows="2" name="img_desc[]" id="img_desc" style="max-width: 100%;" placeholder="Add description"></textarea><span class="remove_img_preview1"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></span></div><div style="display:inline-block;">&nbsp;</div>'].join(''); 
                  document.getElementById('image').insertBefore(span1, null);
                };
              })(f);
              reader.readAsDataURL(f);
            }
        }
    </script>
    ///
    ////upload-photo-action.php
    if(isset($_POST['upload_pho'])){
        $errors= array();
        foreach($_FILES['image_file_photo']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
            $file_name = $key.$_FILES['image_file_photo']['name'][$key];
            $file_size = $_FILES['image_file_photo']['size'][$key];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['image_file_photo']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $file_type = $_FILES['image_file_photo']['type'][$key];
            $image_desc = $_POST['img_desc'][$key];


            //if($file_size > 2097152){
                //$errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
            //}

            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mt_image SET image_name = '".$file_name."',
                                                           image_size = '".$file_size."',
                                                           image_tmp = '".$file_tmp."',
                                                           image_desc = '".$image_desc."',
                                                           image_type = '".$file_type."'")or die(mysql_error());
            $desired_dir = "img_upload";
            if(empty($errors)==true){
                if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                    mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                    rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;                
            }
                mysql_query($query);            
            }else{
                print_r($errors);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

**Jquery:**

```
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 $('#upload_form').submit(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
 url: 'upload.php',
 type: 'post',
 data: new FormData(this),
 contentType: false,
 processData: false,
 success: function(result){

 $('#output').html(result);
 }
 });
 });
 });
</script>
```

**Upload.php**

```
<?php 
 $result = ''; 
 if(is_array($_FILES)) 
 { 
 foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $name => $value) 
 { 
 $my_file_name = explode(".", $_FILES['files']['name'][$name]); 
 $extension_name = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif"); 
 if(in_array($my_file_name[1], $extension_name)) 
 { 
 $NewImageName = md5(rand()) . '.' . $my_file_name[1]; 
 $SourcePath = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$name]; 
 $TargetPath = "upload/".$NewImageName; 
 if(move_uploaded_file($SourcePath, $TargetPath)) 
 { 
 $result .= '<div class="col-md-4"><img src="'.$TargetPath.'" class="img-responsive"></div>'; 
 } 
 } 
 } 
 echo $result; 
 } 
 ?>
```